# Starting git and ignoring files for Android

Tags: android, git

I am trying to test using git with my buddy in a small test project. Now I can't figure out the steps to do that. I am not asking for commands but the steps to do so. For example:

1. Create a clone of a repository from a website
2. Upload code
3. Share it with my friend, and so on

I am trying to understand which step comes first. Can anyone give me the steps in order? And also tell me when does the ignoring part come? And does ignoring file at random step number affect the whole process?

Comment: try https://bitbucket.org/

Comment: please just steps :-)

Comment: you can look at the [EGit plugin wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Getting_Started) or [this tutorial at Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would want to upload your code on `github`, if you don't mind others looking at your code.
So, what I suggest is take a look at `git` and `github` if you don't know them already.
With `github`, what you do is:

- Go to a repository and `fork` it- this will create a branch for you on github. For eg. if you clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux/ - you will get a https://github.com/username/linux/ repository.
- Clone it to your local: `git clone <git_repo>` from your local terminal.
- Work on your own local branch, and when you think it's final, `push` it to your forked repo: `git push origin master`
- If you want to share your new code with your friends, share the link to your forked repo
- If you think there's enough contribution you've made, send a pull request to the original repo and ask them to pull your changes

The ignoring part, as you say, can come anytime. The best way is to use github's `.gitignore` file. When you add files to your `.gitignore` file at a random step, remember that the files will still be contained in previous commits, but will not be present in the present and future commits.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but now on my partner's terminal, it's saying access denied. permission denied....while pushing

Comment: Of course, that's because your partner does not have permission to push to your repository. Imagine a situation where anyone can change your code, without your permission :-). Your friend needs to send you a pull request asking you to merge his branch in your master.

Comment: how 's that done then?

Comment: Firstly, you should go through a crash course on git because there are a lot of things that can go wrong. To send a pull request, your friend needs to go to his repo and click on pull request. github will automatically compare his master branch and your master branch and send the pull request to you. You will then be able to compare both your branches and decide if it's worth merging or not.

Comment: I suggest you to go through all of articles in the help section of github: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Register in sites like bitbucket/codebase etc 
2.Create a project repo
3.git clone project-url (you will get url when you create project)
4.After this step you will get an empty folder cloned to your local.
5.copy your project in to that folder.
6.navigate to that folder (project root folder)
7.check git status (you can see the new files)
8. git add all folders
9.git push origin master
```

Add your buddy to this project ( he can also register and get access to this project with your permission)
Done!